# jquery, my function is called x times instead of once

Tags: jquery

In a page trigger.php I'm loading content.php like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#trigger', function () {
        $('#content').load('content.php');
});
```

In content.php I have this Jquery code:

```
$(function() {

    clickLike = function(el,el2) {
        alert(el+el2);
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.like', function(){
        clickLike($(this).attr('id'),'yes');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#exit', function () { $('#content').html(''); });
    $(document).off('click', '.like', clickLike);

});
```

so when I'm clicking for the first time one #trigger, content.php is loaded and when I'm clicking on .like I have one alert. Then I'm clicking on exit, I'm loading again content.php and when I'm clicking on .like I have now 2 alerts, and if I'm doing it x times I will have x alert. I don't get why .off doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you execute the jQuery code in content.php you're binding the onclick function for .like with an anonymous function that happens to call clickLike().

Later in the code it looks like you're attempting to unbind that using off(), to avoid multiple event bindings, but you're specifying clickLike as the handler to remove, which isn't there in the first place.

To unbind an event handler you either need to specify the exact handler that you bound (which you can't do with an anonymous function), or don't specify the handler at all, in which case all handlers will be unbound.

Also, I presume you only want to unbind in the "exit" handler, not always as you have above.

So I think the following would work for you (but I haven't tested it)

```
$(function() {

    clickLike = function(el,el2) {
        alert(el+el2);
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.like', function(){
        clickLike($(this).attr('id'),'yes');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#exit', function () { 
        $('#content').html(''); 
        $(document).off('click', '.like');
    });

});
```